# NAO applications using ROS

Tags: ros

I want to develop an application for NAO robot using ROS (I already started to use ROS with NAO). But I don't know how to choose a scenario for my robot depending on ROS packages (SLAM, objects recognition...).

My question is: is there any ROS packages for NAO applications that i can started with (turtlebot robot for example has the navigation stacks -SLAM- in ROS).

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: Navigation with NAO is tricky unless you mount a kinect-like sensor on his head, and still the nature of the bipedal walking itself makes it really difficult to model the robot's motion in contrast to simple robots with a differential drive like the turtlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few NAO related packages available for ROS. One of them is a Kinect based teleoperation package: which may not have been updated recently.

http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Using%20Kinect%20to%20Teleoperate%20Nao%20without%20cross-compiling%20%28electric%20on%20NaoQi%201.12%29

But on the bigger scheme of things, perhaps you can try setting up MoveIt! for NAO, and subsequently use it for motion planning on the arms.

https://github.com/ros-naoqi/nao_moveit_config/blob/master/tuto/tuto_moveit.rst

There is also a NAO path follower stack at http://wiki.ros.org/nao_path_follower

Comment: what about the navigation stack for NAO??

Comment: Edited answer with another link to a naoqi stack for path following, given localization is already there.

Comment: ok, I will see that. thank you very much for your answer again.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it has sufficiently addressed your question.